# Как работает функция map()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как работает функция `map(f, a, b)` в *Python 3.5*?
В интернете не нашел примеры вызова.

Comment: `>>> print(map(lambda x, y: x + y, a, b))`
`<map object at 0x1056a5470>`
такое получаеться

Comment: Добавьте list перед map, и будет вам список. Так как в python 3 вам возвращается итератор, а не список как в python 2.

Comment: @Avernial: проще звезду добавить: `print(*map(..`, чтобы передать каждый возвращаемый `map()` элемент как отдельный аргумент для `print()` функции.

Comment: Да, конечно, можно распаковку использовать.

Comment: [примеры с map на Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpython-3.*%5d%20map%28)

Answer (score 5):

[Функция map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) итерирует коллекции, которые в нее передаются, применяя к элементам коллекций функцию и возвращает объект-итератор с результатом выполнения той функции.

Семантика функции такая: `map(function, iterable, ...)`

Минимальный и простейший пример -- это конвертация списка строк в список чисел, пример:

```
>>> map(int, ["1", "2", "3", "4"])
<map object at 0x...
```

Как видно, мы получили объект, а не список, так и должно быть, а чтобы получить список, нужно:

```
>>> list(map(int, ["1", "2", "3", "4"]))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Сейчас я перехожу к самой сути вопроса с `map(f, a, b)`.

Если же в `map` помещать не одну коллекцию, а несколько, то функция получит в аргументы за раз по одному элементу из каждой коллекции:

```
def f(a, b):
    return int(a), int(b)

>>> a = ["1", "2"]
>>> b = ["3", "4"]
>>> list(map(f, a, b))
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Еще больше коллекций:

```
def f(a, b, c):
    return int(a), int(b), int(c)

>>> a = ["1", "2"]
>>> b = ["3", "4"]
>>> c = ["5", "6"]
>>> list(map(f, a, b, c))
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Comment: Если позанудствовать, то возвращается объект-итератор, а не генератор.

Comment: @mkkik, ничего страшного -- занудствуйте :) исправил :)